# r: zApply in parallel computing

Tags: r, parallel-processing, aggregate, raster

I need to aggregate a rasterbrick into monthly values. Normally, this would be easy by using `zApply` function from `raster` package. However, I have a large rasterbrick and this would take a very long time.

So basically, I am wondering if this would be easy to do it with some libraries like `parallel` or `clusterR` but I have no clue how to parallelize this process

```
# create a random raster stack

library(raster)

lay <- stack()

for (i in 1:365){
  print(i)
  ras <- matrix(rnorm(500, mean = 21, sd = rnorm(21, 12, 4)))
  ras <- raster(ras)
  lay <- addLayer(lay, ras)
}

dats <- seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), length.out = nlayers(lay), by = 'days')

lay <- setZ(lay, dats)

monthlies <- zApply(lay, by = format(dats,"%m"), fun = 'mean') # aggregate from daily to monthly.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use foraech and doParallel packages

You can use `foreach` and `doParallel` to achieve your result. 
You will need to:

- Detect the number of your CPU cores with `detectCores()`
- Initialize `DoParallel` to work with your CPU cores with `registerDoParallel(numCores)`
- Setup the `foreach` loop with the needed **packages**, any **init** variable, and a method to **combine** the results.

Your code will look like this:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(raster)

lay <- stack()

## Loading required package: iterators

numCores <- detectCores()
registerDoParallel(numCores)  # use multicore, set to the number of our cores

lay <- foreach (i=1:365, .init = lay, .combine = addLayer , .packages = "raster") %dopar% {
  print(i)
  ras <- matrix(rnorm(500, mean = 21, sd = rnorm(21, 12, 4)))
  ras <- raster(ras)
}

dats <- seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), length.out = nlayers(lay), by = 'days')
lay <- setZ(lay, dats)
monthlies <- zApply(lay, by = format(dats,"%m"), fun = 'mean') # aggregate from daily to monthly

# When you're done, clean up the cluster
stopImplicitCluster()
```

#### Measuring speed improvement

You can test the speed improvement using `System.time()`. These are my results:

```
#Time with a standard for loop
system.time({
  for (i in 1:365){
    print(i)
    ras <- matrix(rnorm(500, mean = 21, sd = rnorm(21, 12, 4)))
    ras <- raster(ras)
    lay <- addLayer(lay, ras)
  }
})

user  system elapsed 
66.29    0.09   67.15 

#Testing foreach loop time
system.time({
  lay <- foreach (i=1:365, .init = lay, .combine = addLayer , .packages = "raster") %dopar% {
    print(i)
    ras <- matrix(rnorm(500, mean = 21, sd = rnorm(21, 12, 4)))
    ras <- raster(ras)
  }
})

user  system elapsed 
21.72    0.09   25.58
```

As we can see, there was an effective speed improvement by using this method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Louis. This is faster indeed. But the issue here is actually the temporal aggregation. I am trying to make zApply function to work in parallel, in order to speed up the aggregation process.

Comment: You're welcome @AndreiNiță. The problem with `zApply` is that it's an experimental function and I couldn't find anything to make it works. You could try using a `foreach` loop instead of `zApply`.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am usually a fan of keeping all my workflow in `R`, this is definitely one instance where using external applications like `CDO` or `NCO` is way more beneficial (i.e. faster). In particular, you can use the `CDO` operators `monmean` or `monavg` in case you want to have an average of every single month in your timeseries, or you can use `ymonmean` if you want a single average for each month of the year (i.e. climatologies).

The commands would look something like:

```
cdo monmean in.nc out.nc
cdo ymonmean in.nc out.nc
```

where in.nc would be your NetCDF file, and out.nc would the NetCDF file resulting from the command.

If you files are split, for example, one file per day, you might consider concatenating everything together with something like:

```
cdo cat *_daily.nc daily_time_series.nc
```